# Should we add e.g. an "immigration" tag to help us (automatically) filter questions that should go to our sister site?

Tags: discussion, tagging, close-reasons

We have regularly been receiving questions about immigration, and now we finally have the possibility to move them to our sister site. I'm aware that not every off-topic question is actually a good question, but an easy way to pick out the immigration questions might be of use.

Could it be a good idea if we added "honey-pot"-tags to our site, such as "immigration", so that we have a way to easily identify the questions that should be moved?

Comment: Stack Exchange regards such use of tags as "meta tags" and the official stance is that they are bad practice. There's a blog post about it from a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 1):

No, for several reasons.

There is no sister site about immigration. I assume you're thinking about [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), but that's about expatriates, i.e. people who are living outside their own country, not about immigrants, i.e. people who are changing countries.

We get very few questions about immigration. We get more questions that are relevant to expatriates, but most of them are on-topic here, and **questions that are on-topic here should not be migrated**. Questions about border crossings, for example, are about travel regardless of any consideration about visa status. Other examples I remember (but didn't keep the links, sorry) include buying a car abroad or opening a bank account (which [Expatriates](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137/are-flag-planting-questions-on-topic) would reject because “you have no intention of moving [there]”).

In any case, tags are not intended to create ghettos, [nor to tell something about what should be done with the question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). they're intended to indicate what the question is about. If a question is *about immigration*, tag it [immigration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration). If not, don't tag it. That's only very loosely related to whether the question is about travel (on-topic) or not (off-topic).

Comment: Immigrant - described by local of destination; Emigrant - described by the local of country he leaves; Expat - described by himself. There isn't real difference, it's the same person described from the different point of view.

Comment: @vartec Yes, but what does this have to do with the price of fish?

Comment: Immigration is specifically on topic, I believe, on expats.SE - though its name might not reflect that it would be unweildy to include all on-topic stuff in the site name.

Comment: I think @vartec's point is that there *is* a site about Immigration, it just uses a different, near-synonym, as its title.